# Launch python script from other computers

Tags: python, executable

which might not even have Python. I'm making dozens of scripts for my company but it only just now dawned on me that people might not even be able to use them.

I'm asking here because I'm not sure what keywords I would use on Google.

So the question is - can I somehow package Python+external libraries into one executable? Or do you know of another way to cirucmvent this?

Comment: Are those scripts going to be executed on the remove server?

Comment: Weird enough Googling the tags you used yielded this: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki

Comment: Yes. I will copy my scripts to a shared folder that everyone can access.

Comment: Oh wow, can't believe I missed that. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

There are several such utilities

I've used py2exe from py2exe.org